# SDL Web 8 unable to list users from Domain and added users

Tags: web8, authorization

I try to search and add new user from domain in SDL Web 8. I got below error:

> (80040356) Unable to list users from "" This request operation sent to net.tcp://localhost:2660/CoreService/201501/netTcp did not receive a reply within the configured timeout (00:10:00). The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout. This may be because the This request operation sent to net.tcp://localhost:2660/CoreService/201501/netTcp did not receive a reply within the configured timeout (00:10:00). The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout. This may be because the service is still processing the operation or because the service was unable to send a reply message. Please consider increasing the operation timeout (by casting the channel/proxy to IContextChannel and setting the OperationTimeout property) and ensure that the service is able to connect to the client.

[image]

Comment: Adding detailed information like this will help everybody here to answer your question and you will get specific answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The screenshot helps a lot in identifying the issue here, it has nothing to do with a timeout really. The issue is a misunderstanding in how the add user dialog works.

As documented (http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-C5616183-B4F1-4138-B9A7-F8D67692743B):

> In Step 1 of the wizard, select users to add:
>   Select the value Domain for Directory Type and enter the name of your domain in the Domain field.

You have forgotten to enter the name of your domain, and thus a search for the domain `""` (an empty string) is attempted, which is timing out.

Try the search again, after entering the name of your domain, before pressing search.